# Matching and updating columns in Excel from two documents

Tags: windows-7, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm completely green with Excel, whenever I think there has to be a quicker/easier way I usally just GOOGLE it and sure enough I find an answer, fab!
Now I'm trying something a little more tricky and there are lots of variations of users comparing/updating/duplicating and I'm not sure which solution is the one I want.

Here's what I'm doing....
I have two Excel documents - one contains last year's asset entries (Doc 1). I now have this year's assets listed (Doc 2) and I want to update the previous document with the updates.

Column A = Item Numbers

Column B = Room Location

Is there a way for Excel to identify the Item numbers from both documents and update Doc 1 room locations from Doc 2? So Coloumn A should stay the same, but Column B will have changed if the items have moved room location. I hope this makes sense!

I'm currently comparing the rows side-by-side in my screen and manually changing the room locations - there's over 10,000 rows :( Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you upload an example workbook

Answer (score 0):

In column B of workbook 1, you can use

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,[WB2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$10000,2,0)
```

and drag it down to the end of your items on WB1.

This is using [=VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) to take each cell in WB1 column A, match it to WB2 column A and return WB2 column B.

The range `$A$1:$B$10000` can be adjusted to the correct range. If it's not found it will give you `#N/A`

Comment: Thank you! I had added a screenshot of the formula entry on WB1 - is this correct? I'm not seeing any changes?

Comment: @JennCherene I don't see a screenshot. You need to rename the WB2.xlsx to the correct name, and the correct sheet, as well as the correct range.

Comment: Apologies, it seems I need more reputation points to post an image.
This is the formula I'm copying into the first empty box in WB1 Coloumn B: =VLOOKUP(A1:A10317,'\\HP1\Shared\Asset Reports\[HTCAssetReg0814_TEST.xlsx]HartonTCAssetReg02-10-4'!$A$1:$B$14000,2,0)


An #N/A simply appears in the box. 'A value is not available for the formula to funtion' ??

Comment: @JennCherene don't define the range `(A1:A10317)`, just use `A1`

Comment: it seems I had my WB 1 & 2 mixed up, which wouldn't have helped! However, I now have the right doc locations/sheet names and range but I'm still just getting #N/A?

=VLOOKUP(A1,[HTCAudit0814ParsedData_TEST.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$13798,2,0)

Comment: @JennCherene make sure both workbooks are open. Make sure what you're looking up is in the same format as what you're looking in. Make sure there aren't any blank spaces, leading or trailing, etc. Make sure what you're looking up exists, as `#N/A` indicates the value was not found

Comment: please bare with me, I really appreciate your time here :-) I have double check all names etc. Everything seems right. I know the two WBs are linked now becasue when I deleted a row out of WB2, the range_lookup automatically went down. But I'm still not seeing anything different.

Can I check... I am putting the formula in the first empty box of WB1/Column B (I have had to input an empty row here), or am I putting the formula into the box with the first value in Column B?
And I'm no longer dragging the bllue box down to the end of my items so that the range stays at A1 ??

Comment: My two WBs: http://i109.photobucket.com/albums/n69/jenncherene/ExcelWorkbooks1amp2_zpsccfe444f.jpg

Comment: The formula in the first empty box in WB1/Column B: http://i109.photobucket.com/albums/n69/jenncherene/ExcelWB1VLOOKUP_zpsce8d0504.jpg

Comment: @JennCherene you put it at the first cell where you want the location to be updated to what's on the other sheet. Then drag it down. This will update each location in column B to what the cell in A next to it has in the other sheet. As you drag it, it will start with `A2` at B2, then at B3 it will become `A3`

Comment: I'm really sorry, this just isnt working lol. My two workbooks start with exactly the same values in Columns A & B, I want WB1 Column B to change to whats in WB2 Column B, according to their matching IDs in Columns A; which box do I enter the formula in and then which column do it drag the blue box down?
I am an absolute dummy on this, I simply need "WB1, Column B, Box 1" (which doesn't work btw).

Comment: in WB1 you put the formula in B2. Drag it down. The formula should be `=VLOOKUP(A2,[WB2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$10000,2,0)`